# How not to exclude null from where not like condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

In where clause for my query if I include condition in where clause such as

```
where 
      T2.Comments not like '%ABC%' 
  and T2.Comments not like '%xyz%'
```

it also filters out blanks/null comments.
I do not want it to filter out null or blanks.

What is another way to filter out eg. `ABC` and `xyz` and also not exclude nulls/blanks?

rest of where caluse.. (after adding bottom two condition I do not get any nulls.

```
Where
    T1.OUT_NO = T2.OUT_NO 
AND T3.OUT_NO = T1.OUT_NO 
AND CAUSE_CAP.CAUSE_NO NOT IN (1,3,5,7,9) 
AND ("T1"."TIME_STAMP">=TO_DATE ('01-04-2013 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND "T1"."TIME_STAMP"<TO_DATE ('06-04-2013 23:59:59', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) 
AND NOT (CAUSE_CAP.CAUSE_NO = 13 AND START_TABLE.TABLE_NO = 83)
AND T2.Comments not like '%ABC%'
AND T2.Comments not like '%XYZ%'
```

Comment: Can you please example which one?

Comment: I moved it to ANSI format FULL OUTER JOIN. was that you were pointing to ?

Comment: OH see now, quotations thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just add `NULL` as a specific case. [edited to show how to generalise this approach to OPs more complex query]

```
Where
    T1.OUT_NO = T2.OUT_NO 
AND T3.OUT_NO = T1.OUT_NO 
AND CAUSE_CAP.CAUSE_NO NOT IN (1,3,5,7,9) 
AND ("T1"."TIME_STAMP">=TO_DATE ('01-04-2013 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND "T1"."TIME_STAMP"<TO_DATE ('06-04-2013 23:59:59', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) 
AND NOT (CAUSE_CAP.CAUSE_NO = 13 AND START_TABLE.TABLE_NO = 83)
AND (T2.Comments IS NULL OR 
        (T2.Comments not like '%ABC%'
         AND T2.Comments not like '%XYZ%')
    )
```

Comment: I have more conditions before NOT LIKE can you please see updated where clause.

Answer (score 4):

When you have a condition `(column LIKE 'somecode')` then all `NULL` values are excluded from the results. Only rows that have not null can result in the condition being true. So, I think you want:

```
where  
      (   (   T2.Comments not like '%ABC%' 
          and T2.Comments not like '%xyz%'
          )
      or  T2.Comments IS NULL 
      )
```

`AND` has higher precedence than `OR` so the inner parentheses are not needed, only added for clarity (as @horse_with_no_name's comment). The outer ones are not needed either if you have only this condition.

In other DBMS, you would also need `or T2.Comments = ''` but not in Oracle, because `NULL` and the empty string are the same thing for char columns.

Comment: Even though `and` binds stronger than `or` I would still add brackets to the condition to make the intention clear.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try using a Case Statement, easy to read and gives you lots of flexibility to add additional conditions.

```
AND CASE WHEN t2.Comments IS NULL THEN 1
         WHEN T2.Comments like '%ABC%' THEN 0
         WHEN T2.Comments like '%xyz%' THEN 0
         ELSE 1 
         END = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

nvl(t2.comments,' ')  like '%xyz%'

Answer (score -1):

Putting it into a 'not like all' statement is making the intention clear and shortens the code for a better overview.

```
    and (T2.Comments not like all ('%ABC%','%xyz%') or T2.Comments is null)
```

Comment: The question is tagged as Oracle DB where this syntax is not supported (not like all).